# Apex Trigger Validation Rule to Prevent Contracts to be created if User is not an Account Team Member

Tags: contracts

I'm not a Developer and I'm trying to build an APEX Trigger that prevent Contracts to be created if the User who is creating the contract is not an Account Team Member for that particular account where he is trying to create the contract.

What I want to achieve is that a User can only create contract in a particular account if he is an account team member in that particular account.

Not sure how to write it, as it's very different from declarative Validation Rules, so I've basically started writing the following, but I'm unable to finish it.

trigger Prevent_User_To_Create_Contracts on Contract (Before insert, before update) {
for(Contract c:trigger.new) {
if(c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit involved. [AccountTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm) records have a lookup to the Account which means you'll likely want to bulkify your trigger.

Here's a strategy you can start with and try to implement after reading the docs:

1. Look for the AccountTeamMembers by **Contract.AccountId** in a SOQL query and return the **UserId** field
2. See if the collection *[(Set or Map)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)* of **UserId** contains the **OwnerId** of the Contract record owner.
3. If the check fails/returns false, add an error to the record **[c.addError()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError)**;

Answer (score 0):

Following your recommendations, I was trying to insert the following class but is not working and I'm not sure why:

public class ContractPreventAccountTeamMembers{

public static void execute(List contracts){
Map<Id,Id> contractAccountMap = new Map<Id,Id> ();
for(Contract contract :contracts)
contractAccountMap.put(contract.Id, contract.AccountId);

Map, Set> accountTeamMemberMap = Map, Set>();
for(AccountTeamMember accountTeamMember :[SELECT Id, AccountId, accountAccessLevel
FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId IN :contractAccountMap.value() AND accountAccessLevel ='Read/Write'])

{
Set accountTeamMemberIds = new Set ();
if(accountTeamMemberMap.containsKey(accountTeamMember.AccountId))
accountTeamMemberIds = accountTeamMemberMap.get(accountTeamMember.AccountId)
accountTeamMemberIds.add(accountTeamMember.Id);
accountTeamMemberMap.put(accountTeamMember.AccountId, accountTeamMemberIds);
}

account team member con R/W y comprobamos que el User esté en ese conjunto de account team member
for(Contract contract :contracts){
if(!(accountTeamMemberMap.containsKey(contract.AccountId) && accountTeamMemberMap.get(contract.AccountId).contains(UserInfo.getUserId())))
contract.addError('mensaje');
}
}
}

Comment: for a list you need to use the <> around the type: <Contract>